# How do I create a global JSP variable that I can access across multiple pages or inside frames/iframes?

Tags: java, html, jsp, variables, global-variables

Simply, how do I create a global variable in JSP, such that I can access it across other JSP pages and/or inside frames/iframes?  I tried <%!..%> but I got an error that the variable could not be resolved in a separate jsp page.  Is it even possible to access JSP variables in more than one page without resorting to query strings, session variables, etcetera?

Thank you.

Comment: Nope - you need session variables / query string / HTTP POST

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you cannot use session variables?

Comment: No, not at all.  I just thought there might be an alternative.

Comment: Use [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) to keep your variables alive in the application scope.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Thank you very much.  Would you please cite an example?  Or, please provide an external resource which provides information on how to define my own variables using ServletContext?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've already commented, you can use [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) to maintain the variables for all your application. Do not confuse this with static variables, because the ServletContext will die when your application is undeployed but static variables will be alive until the JVM is turned off.

You can save variables in ServletContext by using [`setAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method. Also, you can get the actual value by using [`getAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29). Let's see a sample of ServletContext in a servlet:

```
public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        String someAttribute = servletContext.getAttribute("someAttribute");
        System.out.println("someAttribute value: " + someAttribute);
    }
}
```

Also, you can use a Listener to ServletContext, so you can execute some code when the application starts (is deployed correctly) to initialize the attributes on the ServletContext) and when it finish (before its undeployed).

```
public final class MyAppListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Application gets started.");
        ServletContext servletContext = event..getServletContext();
        servletContext.setAttribute("someAttribute", "Hello world!");
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Application has finished.");
    }
}
```

If you're using Java EE 5, you should configure the listener in the web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>mypackage.listener.MyAppListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is great.  I can see how you created the ServletContext variables, manipulated them, and destroyed them when the application exited.  Thank you very much for your help.  It is most appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still have few confusions: Where de we write this code? Should I just make a new java file in SourcePackages, if so, when and where do I instantiate this class.

Comment: @d34th4ck3r every `Listener` is a different class, so it will be better to create a new class e.g. `MyAppListener` and add the `implements ServletContextListener` and the code there. You can find examples of this in the net e.g. [What is Listener – ServletContextListener Example](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/). And you do not instantiate this class, the application server will do it for you.

Comment: How can we use this attribute in different jsp pages?

Comment: @TLE use Expression Language: `${someAttribute}` it will automatically search for the attribute in application scope.