# JSP Global Variable using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a date format at I wish to set globally for my jsp fmt tag to use.

May I know what is right approach to perform this?

I will wish to configure this value in future

pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy kkm"

I have read the following:

[How do I create a global JSP variable that I can access across multiple pages or inside frames/iframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107962/how-do-i-create-a-global-jsp-variable-that-i-can-access-across-multiple-pages-or)

Answer (score 0):

I think using applicationContext is right approach. You can set your date format at your `"welcomepage.jsp"`,

```
 String pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy kkm";
application.setAttribute("ApplicationPattern",pattern);
```

get and use the same format wherever required.

```
String pattern2 =(String)getServletContext().getAttribute("ApplicationPattern");
```

Comment: how do I get in the JSP page?

Comment: Use   String pattern2 =(String)getServletContext().getAttribute("ApplicationPattern"); , You get the pattern apply wherever you want.

Comment: resolved thanks but I am using Spring so the solution is slightly difference

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the default data-format pattern for entire app, you could use ServletContext.setAttribute(), but you need a place to do this work, set it in a jsp page or use a initialize filter for your app.

Or you create a Utlitiy class with a static method(field) definition to get the default pattern, then from your `fmt`
 tag use a method call to reference the default pattern